# Input vs :Input in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I wonder why people seems to prefer `:input` over `input` as a jQuery selector? Basically, this two lines seem to do the same thing :

```
$('input:first').focus()
$(':input:first').focus()
```

But second version is more widely use, and I don't find why. Moreover, the `:input` selector seem slower according to this benchmark: http://jsperf.com/input-vs-input/2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`:input` is pseudo selector by jQuery which includes `<buttons>`, `<textarea>`, e.t.c

`input` is a tag match which strictly matches `<input>`.

This additional note about `:input` is informative:

> Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:input` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:input` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":input")`.

--from https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 4):

`input` is just the input element selector.  [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) also selects `textarea`, `select`, and `button` (form controls).

It's not necessarily a matter of preference since in actuality they do somewhat different things.

Answer (score 1):

[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selects all input, textarea, select and button elements, while `input` just selects elements with an input tag.